# open source iphone like SMS UI interface

Tags: ios, open-source, chat

I am new to ios development. 
I am looking to build a small application that resembles iphone's built in chat.
Does anyone know of any open source project that imitates the chat interface?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this - http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-bubble-ui-iphone-apps

you can download source from here http://www.mediafire.com/?w2p0dfjbad3vcvy.